# How to create a ubuntu user from within node

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, user-management

I'm trying to add users to the server running my node application. Right now I am using:

```
exec("useradd -mp {password-hash}")
```

with a hash that gets created by

```
exec("mkpasswd -m des {password}")
```

This leaves the password visible in the process list, and that should be avoided at all costs.

That's why I am wondering if there is a module on npm or an easier way to add a linux user to the system programmatically (this is necessary because the app I am building creates a user account on the system when a user registers on the web). Can this be done without evoking system commands like I am currently doing? I have found neither npm module nor any information of using node to interact with ubuntu/unix user management.

## Solution

Using Mustafa's hints from the top answer, I implemented a version of the `mkpasswd` command using `spawn`. In CoffeeScript, it would look like this:

```
{spawn} = require 'child_process'

child = spawn 'mkpasswd', ['-m','des','--stdin']

child.stdout.on 'data', (data)->
  console.log 'password hash arrived: ', data.toString()

child.stdin.write 'password'
```

Make sure you add the proper error handling event handlers to `child.stderr` and `child.stdout` while debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either use those commands or manually add your user to `/etc/passwd` and its password to  `/etc/shadow`.

Format of a `/etc/passwd` entry: `username:passwd:UID:GID:full_name:directory:shell`

Passwd should be x if you want it o make it secure, so it will read from shadow.

Format of a `/etc/shadow` entry: `username:passwd:last:may:must:warn:expire:disable:reserved`

If you add them correctly, there will be no problem.

But why would you bother with it manually while you have the required tool? If you are concerned about the privacy, you can issue `mkpasswd -m des --stdin` which will read the password from standart input. Instead of exec, when you use `spawn`, you can also control the `stdin` and `stdout` of the processes. `stdin` is just a writable stream, you can write to it and read the output from `stdout`. Or you can find a npm module that generates the hash with given algorithms, DES, AES etc.

Comment: Thank you for the hints, particularly the one with `spawn`, I'll try implementing that one. 

I failed horribly at generating the hash via npm modules, since the crypt(3) seems to implement a non-standard DES algorithm.